# Populate field with value of another field jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's .change event to populate a fields value (#value2) with another fields value (#value1).

#value1 can be also populated dynamically via query string (using Gravity Forms feature) so .change doesn't work until the user manually changes the field value.

How can I update #value2 with #value1 on page load?

```
jQuery('#value1').on('change', function() {
   jQuery('#value2').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: wrap the code in document ready. then manually call the change event like  `jQuery('#value1').on('change', function() {
   jQuery('#value2').val(this.value);
}).change();`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is trigger the change event while updating the field dynamically. For that use **[`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** method.

```
jQuery('#value1').trigger('change')
```

or use shorthandler of that like

```
jQuery('#value1').change()
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the window load event to fire, then get the value from one of the fields and apply it to the other.

```
$(window).load(function(){
       var val1 = $('#value1').val();
         $('#value2').val(val1);

});
```